# Hide and Show Toggle that Functions in PC and Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, cross-browser, toggle

I have a toggle switch that displays/hides the next element using an `onclick`:

```
function toggleSwitch(z){
        var x,a;
        x=/(di-0)/i;
        if(x.test(z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue)){a=1}else{a=0}
        switch (a){
            case 1:
                z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-2';
                break;
            case 0:
                z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-0';
                break;
            }
    }
```

How do I write a JavaScript that would possibly be compatible with most of the PC and Mobile browsers?

#### Demo

```js
    function toggleSwitch(z){
        var x,a;
        x=/(di-0)/i;
        if(x.test(z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue)){a=1}else{a=0}
        switch (a){
            case 1:
                z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-2';
                break;
            case 0:
                z.d.nextElementSibling.attributes.getNamedItem('class').nodeValue='di-0';
                break;
            }
    }
```

```css
.di-0{display:none!important}.di-1{display:inline-block}.di-2{display:block}.di-3{display:grid}
```

```html
    <div class="ro">
        <a href="#" class="s18 ro tx-1 b119 r100 t-21 p-2 br-5 mv-3" onclick="toggleSwitch({d:this});return false;" title="A latest quote"> Average Daily Equilibrium Forecast: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT</a>
        <div class="di-0">Display Some Content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What compatibility issues have you run into?

Comment: Using CSS class names to do this is 100% reliable, just as you're doing it.

Comment: You can use the jQuery library and do this in a small amount of code `$(z).next().toggle();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you can use the [details](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp) and [summary](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp) tags (both new in HTML5) for this purpose.

It's widely supported on both mobile and desktop browsers, except the pseudo-browsers *Internet Explorer*, *Edge* and *Edge Mobile*.

Well, JavaScript comes to the rescue if we want to make sure that our toggle thing works on both real and pseudo-browsers. (Sorry jQuery, not this time. You can save the world another time.)

**Solution with JavaScript without jQuery**

Notes:

1. Using the anchor element (`a`) is not a good idea, since it has another semantic and functional meaning. You can use a `button` element for instance, which fits better both in semantic and functional sense. However, becausue there is additional work for making a button looks nicer, I just replaced the `a` with a `div` element instead. You can also use the `cursor: pointer` CSS property for this `div` to achieve the same visual effect like the `a` has.
2. You should avoid ambiguous named variables. For better readability and easier maintenance in the future, always give your variables a meaningful name.
3. I renamed the function `toggleSwitch` as `toggleNext`, since it tells more about the purpose of the button. Further you can simply work with [Java Script Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp), if you want to access the source DOM element via `event.target`
4. The `toggleNext` function has an additional optional parameter called `display`. Which is by default `block`, and used to set the visible display state of the next sibling element. It should give you more playroom, since you can simply pass the display value for an arbitrary sibling element like `toggleNext(event, 'grid')`
5. In the `toggleNext(event, display)` function, we first get the `siblingElem` from our reference element (`event.target`) and then check whether its display property has the 'none' value, if so then we need to toggle the state by simply assigning a new display value to that element.
6. In the initial state `siblingElem.style.display` has the value `null`, thus we check `!siblingElem.style.display`, this is necessary for the first time.

   - In JavaScript `!null` and `!undefined` are resolved as `truthy`
   - More information about [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)
7. For the sake of clarity, I removed the classes (`s18 ro tx-1 b119 r100 t-21 p-2 br-5 mv-3`) from the `div` element you provided  in your OP.

```html
<div class="ro">
  <div class="toggle-button" onclick="toggleNext(event)" title="A latest quote">
      Average Daily Equilibrium Forecast: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT
  </div>
  <div>Display Some Content</div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Display pointer on hover */
.toggle-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the next sibling element - does not matter what type it is */
.toggle-button + * {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
function toggleNext(event, display) {
  var siblingElem = event.target.nextElementSibling;

  if (!siblingElem) return;

  display = display || 'block';

  if (!siblingElem.style.display || siblingElem.style.display === 'none') {
    siblingElem.style.display = display;
  } else {
    siblingElem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/emma-toggle-2-1?file=index.html

Now you have even more playroom, you can logically tie one toggle button to another one like so:

```html
<div class="ro">
  <div class="toggle-button" onclick="toggleNext(event)" title="A latest quote">
      Average Daily Equilibrium Forecast: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT
  </div>
  <div>
    Display Some Content

    <div class="toggle-button" onclick="toggleNext(event)" title="A latest quote">
          Average Daily Equilibrium Forecast: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT
    </div>
    <div>
      Display Some Another Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/emma-toggle-2-2?file=index.html

**Solution without JavaScript (`<details>`)**

```html
<details>
  <summary> Average Daily Equilibrium Forecast: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT</summary>
  Display 
  Some 
  Content
  
</details>
<br>
<details>
  <summary>Another entry: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT</summary>
  <h1>Display some other content</h1>
</details>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/emma-toggle-1-1?file=index.html

Further, you can also nest a `details` into another `details` tag:

```
<details>
  <summary> Average Daily Equilibrium Forecast: Monday, 13 May 2019 ⏱ 19:07 EDT</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>
      Display  Some  Content
    </summary>
    <h1>Display some other content</h1>
  </details>
</details>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/emma-toggle-1-2?file=index.html

Last but not least, you can hide the showed arrow that is displayed by default for the `<details>` tag, if you wish:

```css
  /* this is for Chrome */
  details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display:none;
  }
  /* this is for Firefox */
  details summary {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
```